# Efficient line-by-line dataframe generation in polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Given a mechanism/system that generates data row-by-row and a `decompose` function that decomposes a row into its data features, what is the most efficient way to capture this data in a polars dataframe and periodically flush this dataframe to disk.

The two possibilities I come up with are either iteratively building lists, then buidling a dataframe and flushing it to disk like so:

```py
import polars as pl
# just two features for simplicity
feature_a_list = []
feature_b_list = []
flush_threshold = 100
count = 0
for row in generation_mechanism():
    feature_a,feature_b = decompose(row)
    feature_a_list.append(feature_a)
    feature_b_list.append(feature_b)
    count+=1
    if count==flush_threshold:
        data = pl.DataFrame({"feature_a":feature_a_list,"feature_b":feature_b_list})
        with open('filename.csv', 'a') as file:
            data.write_csv(file)
```

or building a dataframe for every row and concatenating or vstacking them together like so:

```py
import polars as pl
flush_threshold = 100
count = 0
data = pl.DataFrame(schema={"feature_a":pl.String,"feature_b":pl.String})
for row in generation_mechanism():
    feature_a,feature_b = decompose(row)
    new_data = pl.DataFrame({"feature_a":feature_a,"feature_b":feature_b})
    data = data.vstack(new_data)
    count+=1
    if count==flush_threshold:
        with open('filename.csv', 'a') as file:
            data.write_csv(file)
```

I am wondering which of the above solutions is preferable/canonical/more efficient or whether there are other views on this problem that I have overlooked.
Thanks!

Comment: If all you're doing is writing a CSV, I would imagine it's cheaper to just use the csv module.

Comment: Familiarity was guiding my design decision here plus the possibility to implement other serialization methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [`LazyFrame`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/index.html) from generator using `generation_mechanism()` function and then save it to csv in streaming mode via [`sink_csv`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_csv.html):

```py
def generation_mechanism():
    for x in range(1000000):
        yield (x, x + 1)

lf = pl.LazyFrame(generation_mechanism(), schema=["feature_a","feature_b"])
lf.sink_csv("test.csv", batch_size=100)
```

If `decompose()` function is a bit more complicated than just split into the features, you can use [`map_batches`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.map_batches.html)to apply it:

```py
def decompose(row):
    return row[0]*1, row[1]*3

lf = (
    pl
    .LazyFrame({"a": generation_mechanism()})
    .map_batches(
        lambda x: x.select(pl.col("a").map_elements(decompose)),
        streamable=True
     )
     .select(
         pl.col("a").list.to_struct(fields=["feature_a","feature_b"])
     )
).unnest("a")

lf.sink_csv("test.csv", batch_size=100)
```

**Previous answer**

You could avoid row-by-row dataframe creation by using [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) and [`.Series.map_elements`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.map_elements.html). Even in this case your `decompose()` function will be executed row-by-row unless you rewrite it in a vectorized way, which should be much faster.

Test functions:

```py
def generation_mechanism():
    for x in range(10):
        yield (x, x + 1)

def decompose(row):
    return row[0], row[1]
```

You can create `batch` dataframes like this:

```py
from itertools import batched

flush_threshold = 3

for batch in batched(generation_mechanism(), flush_threshold):
    df = pl.DataFrame(
        pl
        .Series(batch)             # create pl.Series for given batch
        .map_elements(decompose)   # apply decompose function        
        .list.to_struct(fields=["feature_a","feature_b"])
    ).unnest("data")               # transform struct into columns
```

Output:

```py
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ feature_a ┆ feature_b │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 1         │
│ 1         ┆ 2         │
│ 2         ┆ 3         │
└───────────┴───────────┘
...
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ feature_a ┆ feature_b │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 9         ┆ 10        │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: This sounds pretty good, I will try it out and let you know. Thanks already for answering.